# Swagger request validation with multiple swagger specifications

Tags: swagger, swagger-codegen

We want to split our swagger specifications into two files. One containing the endpoints and one containing the type definitions because the type definitions are used in multiple projects and we want to avoid fixing something in multiple source locations.

We are using the maven codegen plugin to generate the model and the api and it works fine with the splitting.

However the request validation does not because it is not able to follow the external references to the type definitions it seems.

We are using swagger-request-validator-springmvc for the request validation. Unfortunately only one resource is allowed and it does not expand/merge the multiple specifications into one as swagger-codegen does.

When running the swagger-codegen in verbose mode a "merged" swagger specification is shown in the log. Is there a way to get codegen to export this merged specification?

Or is there another way to get the request validation going with multiple specification files?

Answer (score 0):

> When running the swagger-codegen in verbose mode a "merged" swagger specification is shown in the log. Is there a way to get codegen to export this merged specification?

If I am understanding this correctly, you want the *whole* swagger specification when using the maven plugin. This is usually generated in the output folder specified in the plugin configuration.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${swagger.codegen.maven.plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
             <phase>generate-sources</phase>
             <goals>
                 <goal>generate</goal>
             </goals>
             <configuration>
                 ...
                 <output>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/swagger</output>
                 ...
             </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I cannot understand your second question however - can you please elaborate?

> Or is there another way to get the request validation going with multiple specification files?

Comment: You did not understand the first part either.
I already have the swagger specification. It is not generated by written by us. The specification consists of more than one yaml file where in one "main" file others are imported.
This works fine when generating the model classes via maven.
However this does not works when validating requests as the swagger-request-validator-springmvc does only take one file as specification and it seems it does not follow imports while parsing the specification.